# What is the definition of Cauchy function associated with the differential or difference equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

What is the definition of Cauchy function associated with the differential or difference equations? Where can I find the details?

Comment: do you mean the cauchy-euler equation?

Comment: No, I mean the Cauchy function x(t,s) which is useful to find the Green function of  the differential or difference equations.

Comment: oop, thats outa my knowledge range sorry for protruding

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy function $y(t,s)$ for difference equations, defined for $a\leq t\leq b+2,\; a+1\leq s\leq b+1,$ is defined as the function that, for each fixed $s\in [a+1,b+1]=\{a+1,a+2,..., b+1\}$, is the solution of the initial value problem $$Ly(t)=0$$ $$y(s,s)=0$$ $$y(s+1,s)=\frac{1}{p(s)}$$
Where $Ly(t)= \Delta(p(t-1)\Delta y(t-1))+q(t)y(t)$ is the self adjoint operator